# Construir un html parser desde cero con Python

Tags: html, python-3.x

Alguien tiene documentacion que me pueda servir como guia para construir un html parser por mi cuenta? es para poder usarlo en un web scraper (tambien contruido por mi cuenta) usando estructuras de datos.
P.d: Es para un proyecto de una materia de la uni, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta esta buscando recomendaciones externas al sitio, lo cual puede conllevar su cierre. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].